# NativeBase: How center text inside of Toast?

Tags: react-native, native-base

The default positioning of text shown by NativeBase's Toast tag is to the left:

[image]

***QUESTION: How do I center "cache cleared" text?***

All these attempts fail to produce desired centering:

```
    Toast.show
        style: justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'
        text: 'cache cleared'
        textStyle: justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'
```

(CoffeeScript)

Comment: Have you tried set textAlign: 'center' on the textStyle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do it

```
Toast.show({
  text: 'Some text',
  position: 'bottom',
  type: 'danger',
  duration: 1000,
  textStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
})
```